# How to break 1 cycle in a for-loop without stopping the whole loop?

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop

I am programming a program that will make a list of all numbers from 1 to 200 that:

- are not divisible by 7 or 11
- do not contain the digit 7 or 11 in their number.

I want to use the pass function so when the condition is not met, it will continue with the next number. I don't really know how to do it. The pass function is probably the wrong one. I know the break function does also not work because it will end the whole loop.

Please explain me how to make this program work on this way. There are probably plenty other ways to calculate this, but the point is that i want to understand how to use the for loops better :).

```
n = 200 #all digits till and including 200

numbers = [] #empty list for accumulation values

for i in range(1,(n+1)):

    if i%7 == 0 or i%11 == 0:   #if one of these 3 conditions are met
        pass                    #it should continue to the next number (i)

    if str(7) in str(i):
        pass
    if str(11) in str(i):
        pass

    numbers.append(i)
print(numbers)
print(sum(numbers)) # for my assignment i need to sum the list
```

Comment: I guess you just want to use `continue` keyword. It does exactly what you need, breaks only current iteration of loop and returns to its beginning. It should be covered next to `for` and `break` concepts in any decent tutorial/book.

Comment: `break` and `pass` are not functions, they are statements. You probably want to use [`continue`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops)

Comment: If all you do is `pass`, you don't need those checks.

Comment: ahh, i always tought `continue` was a useless statement because i could not see the value of it. im going to try it

Comment: @Austin, what do you mean, can you explain?

Comment: You **could** try reverse logic: `if i%7 != 0 and i%11 != 0 and '7' not in str(i) and '11' not in str(i): numbers.append(i)`. And then, the pass/continue/break is not necessary at all

Comment: pass simply does nothing, while continue goes on with the next loop iteration. For example  if you want to ignore some exception, you use except SomeException: pass

Comment: @Tomerikoo, i tried tried what you said and it does not work. I get what the pass statement does, it does nothing haha

Comment: `numbers.append(i)` needs un-indenting 1 level.

Comment: @Marco works fine to me...

Comment: @MarkSetchell, that was a typo on the forum, not in my script. i changed it

Comment: @Tomerikoo , i tougth you meant to change my statements with what you sent, i get you now, you create one big condition.

Comment: @Marco ah yes I meant another approach. To reverse the logic and avoid the passing part

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use continue in place of pass.

Answer (score 2):

`pass` does nothing

`continue` skips to the next loop

so i had to use `continue` in my example.